# Find the value of $x$ from $\sin(x)+\cos(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(5x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I used auxiliary argument method and converted into $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-5 x\right)$ (by introducing $\sqrt{2}$ as auxiliary argument and then using $\cos(\pi/{4})\cos(x) + \sin(\pi/{4})\sin(x) = \cos(\pi/{4} - x)$ and using $\sin(5x) = \cos(\pi/{2} - 5x)$ )

But the answer isn't matching after using the formula  for $\cos(\theta) = \cos(\alpha)$

I got  $-\frac{\pi(8 n+3)}{24}, \frac{\pi(8 k+1)}{16}$    while the answer is $\frac{\pi(8 n+3)}{24}, \frac{\pi(8 k+1)}{16}$

Comment: @peterwhy I'm getting  $-\frac{\pi(8 n+3)}{24}, \frac{\pi(8 k+1)}{16}$    while the answer is $\frac{\pi(8 n+3)}{24}, \frac{\pi(8 k+1)}{16}$

Comment: @Surb how else can I solve it?

Comment: Put that information into your question, H.v. Also show how you got to $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-5x)$. Otherwise, how can we know where you went wrong?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \sin(a+b+c+d+e) \\ {} \\
= {} & \overbrace{\,\sin a\,}\,\, \overbrace{\,\cos b\cos c\cos d\cos e} \\
& {} + \text{four other terms with one sine and four cosines} \\ {}\\
& {} - {} \overbrace{ \, \sin a\sin b\sin c \,}\,\, \overbrace{\,\cos d\cos e} \\
& {} - \text{ nine other terms with three sines and two cosines} \\{} \\
& {} + \sin a\sin b\sin c\sin d \sin e
\end{align}
$$
$$ \begin{align} & \text{Therefore } \quad \sin(5a) = 5\sin a\cos^4 a - 10\sin^3a\cos^2 a + \sin^5 a. \qquad\qquad\qquad \end{align} $$
Since the powers of cosines are even$,\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: Since the powers of cosines are even, this can be written as a polynomial in $\sin a. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac \pi 4 - x &= 2\pi k \pm \left(\frac\pi2 - 5x\right)\\
\frac \pi 4 - x&= 2\pi k +\frac \pi2 - 5x &\text{or}&&\frac \pi 4 - x&=2\pi k -\frac\pi2 + 5x\\
4x &= 2\pi k +\frac{\pi}4&\text{or}&&-6x &= 2\pi k -\frac{3\pi}{4}\\
x &= \frac{\pi(8k+1)}{16}&\text{or} &&x&= -\frac{\pi(8k\color{red}-3)}{24}\\
&&&&&= \frac{\pi (8n+3)}{24}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How did you go from $x=-\frac{\pi(8k-3)}{24}$ to $x=\frac{\pi(8n+3)}{24}$?

 $-3$ becoming $+3$ is understandable, but how did $8k$ turn to $8n$? Did you assume $-k=n$?

Comment: @hvm Yes, let $-k = n$.

Comment: Can I similarly assume $k=n/2$ (I'm solving another question and the answers aren't matching again)

Comment: @hvm substituting $k=n/2$ alone would introduce incorrect roots for the cases when $n$ is an odd integer. It's usually assumed that $n$ and $k$ can be any integer.

Answer (score 1):

A standard trig formula is

$ \sin (a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$

We can use this to say

$\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2}(\sin x \times 1/\sqrt{2} + \cos x \times 1/\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}(\sin x \cos (\pi/4)+\cos x\sin(\pi/4)) = $

$\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)$

So

$\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}\sin(5x)$

Therefore, $x+\pi/4 = 5x$ (modulo $2\pi$).  And you should be able to take it from there.

Peterwhy's comment reminds me, you also need to take into account that $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\sin(\pi/2+x)$.

Comment: @peterwhy   True.  I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to use *congruences*.

First note the equation can be written as
$$\sin\Bigl(x+\frac\pi 4\Bigr)=\sin 5x \iff \begin{cases}
5x\equiv x+\frac\pi 4 \mod 2\pi\iff 4x\equiv \frac\pi 4 \mod 2\pi \\
\quad\text{ or} \\
5x\equiv \pi - \bigl(x+\frac\pi 4\bigr) \mod 2\pi \iff 6x\equiv \frac{3\pi}4\mod 2\pi.
\end{cases} $$

Can you  proceed from there?